# Consideration of type/unit errors relevant in statistics and correlation studies?

Tags: correlation, units

In http://www.academia.edu/1067827/Defence_of_Empirical_Evidence, Paul Cockshott argues that "type error" must be considered. So, the type of the average cost of the unit of oil is dollars/barrel, while the type of the average of cost of the unit of pencil is dollars/pencil. He argues that these two are basically incomparable, so are inappropriate for correlation studies. My question is, is this true?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally confused. First, a better link for the cited paper is https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c60b/2f66cddfc9ce871318ab17b2d619467815fc.pdf

There, the author argues against some of his critics which have argued (really!) that computing a correlation is a "type error".  That is wrong, and the paper argues clearly why. Calculating the mean of oil price in dollars/barrel and wheat price in euros/ton is meaningless, we cannot sum (or average) measurements with different units. But we **can** correlate them, correlation is unitless.  Details in linked paper.